# How to save value from POST method in jsp to variable in Java class?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

working under my project currently and now have a little problem. What I need,is to save value from POST method in my file.jsp to some variable in Java class,could someone tell me,what I need to use in this case?
thank's!

Comment: What do you mean by "POST method in my file.jsp"?

Comment: it may be useful for u [check](https://www.journaldev.com/7148/java-httpurlconnection-example-java-http-request-get-post)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring MVC? If yes, you can have a parameter annotated with @RequestParam in your controller method to get the value from jsp. The name of the parameter should be the name of your input field or you can specify the name in the annotation if different.

Comment: hi,yeah,I'm using Spring MVC. What kind of code I need to use. Cause I tried once smth like this,and nothing happens(